# Authentication: JWT in RoR and android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, retrofit, jwt

Ruby 2.2.4
Rails 5.0.0.1
retrofit:1.9.0'
otto:1.3.8'

Hello People,

I am just a beginner in programming and I have the task to create an android app with Android Studio, where you can login and logout as a user. Therefore 
I programmed a Token-based authentication in RoR 5 API with Json Web Token (JWT). This tutorial helped me: http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api ). After putting the right credentials in curl I finally receive the token: `{"auth_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE0NjA2NTgxODZ9.xsSwcPC22IR71OBv6bU_OGCSyfE89DvEzWfDU0iybMA"}`

Now after this works fine I tried to implemend the login-function in android studio, which should interact with my RoR server. 
I followed strictly a tutorial (https://www.sitepoint.com/retrofit-a-simple-http-client-for-android-and-java/ )which uses Retrofit for authentication with a php server. However I want to implement this for my RoR server. Nevertheless I tried this code out. I was happy, that the program can communicate with my ruby on rails server. If I login on android app with the right credentials, I see on the console that it will be accepted.

However I dont know how I get a message on android, that the login was succesful plus a welcome message with the name of the user. As I said I use JWT in RoR which gives a long token back. Is there a possibility that retrofit can interpret this token? Or do I need to install JSON Web Token for android? Here is a part of the code in ruby on rails:

**app/commands/authenticate_user.rb**

```
class AuthenticateUser
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(email, password)
    @email = email
    @password = password
  end

  def call
JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :email, :password

  def user
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticate(password)

    errors.add :user_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
    nil
  end
end
```

**lib/json_web_token.rb**

```
class JsonWebToken
  class << self
    def encode(payload, exp = 24.hours.from_now)
      payload[:exp] = exp.to_i
      JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
    end

    def decode(token)
      body = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)[0]
      HashWithIndifferentAccess.new body
    rescue
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

And here comes a part of my android app, which code is from the tutorial I followed:

```
public class Communicator {
    private static  final String TAG = "Communicator";
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/retrofit";

    public void loginPost(String username, String password){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(SERVER_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        Interface communicatorInterface = restAdapter.create(Interface.class);
        Callback<ServerResponse> callback = new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ServerResponse serverResponse, Response response2) {
                if(serverResponse.getResponseCode() == 0){
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceServerEvent(serverResponse));
                }else{
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(serverResponse.getResponseCode(), serverResponse.getMessage()));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if(error != null ){
                    Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(-200,error.getMessage()));
            }
        };
        communicatorInterface.postData("login", username, password, callback);
    }

    public void loginGet(String username, String password){
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(SERVER_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        Interface communicatorInterface = restAdapter.create(Interface.class);
        Callback<ServerResponse> callback = new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ServerResponse serverResponse, Response response2) {
                if(serverResponse.getResponseCode() == 0){
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceServerEvent(serverResponse));
                }else{
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(serverResponse.getResponseCode(), serverResponse.getMessage()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if(error != null ){
                    Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
                BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceErrorEvent(-200,error.getMessage()));
            }
        };
        communicatorInterface.getData("login", username, password, callback);
    }
}
```

This is the Php script from the android tutorial. Maybe I need to transfer this into ruby

```
<?php

    //Post Method here
    if(isset($_POST['method']) == 'login'){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($username == "admin" && $password == "admin"){
            $response = array('returned_username' => "-admin-",
                              'returned_password' => "-admin-",
                              'message' => "Your credentials are so weak [USING_POST]!",
                              'response_code' => "1");
               echo json_encode($response);

        }else{
            $response = array('response_code' => "-1",
                              'message' => "invalid username or password");
               echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

The json encoding in php includes an array (username, password, message, responsecode). How can I include the same array with JWT on ruby on rails? Any idea? And how I get a message on android, that the login was succesful

Answer (score 0):

In the line `JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user`, you're passing a hash with a key `user_id`. You could extend this line to include additional attributes, somewhat like
`JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id, name: user.name) if user`.

You will then need to include a JWT library in your android app and decode the server response (obtained from Retrofit) and you'll be able to access the attributes you encoded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise. I followed your advice and implemented the JWT library and can now encode a token. But I dont know how to get the token. The token appears only in the android console:                                                com.example.programmingknowledge.login D/Retrofit: {"auth_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJuYW1lIjpudWxsLCJlbWFpbCI6ImV4YW1wbGVAbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE0NzMwMzU1MTF9.bhJABvEgtRISZVJ0DejjEtrGJyXzNV6PO0YGQ71xHRc"}

Comment: How can I get the full token in my android app?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to retrieve the token value, first add those lines to your `ServerResponse.java` file:

```
@SerializedName("token")
private String token;

String token

this.token = token;

public String getToken() { return token; }

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

According to what is already there and then go to then main activity and store the token in a variable such as this:

```
String auth_token = serverEvent.getServerResponse().getToken()
```

next you can make it `private final` and use it all over your project.

Hope it helps!